# Amazon AWS user-data not executing on Ubuntu 14.04 AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, user-data

The following `user-data` is not running on a Ubuntu 14.04 AMI that has `cloud-init` package:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -t "test" pwd
```

After the instance has initialized, `screen -r` prints `There is no screen to be resumed.` Is the user-data created incorrectly?

Comment: This line at the top of your user data script gives easy access to errors and warnings output from your commands for debugging:

"exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1"

I write more about it here: http://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-user-data-output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe screen has to be attached to a terminal to run. Scripts run by cloud-init aren't attached to a terminal.

If you want to be sure your user-data script is being run, put something like `echo Running > /tmp/checkit` as the first line (following `#!/bin/bash`) so you can see if it creates the file.